# Error trying to create angular project with .net core 3

Tags: asp.net, angular, .net-core

After I [install dotnet core sdk 3.0](https://github.com/dotnet/core-sdk/blob/master/README.md#installers-and-binaries) and run 'dotnet new angular', I'm getting the following error seen in the pic of powershell. I also included a pic of where I downloaded the latest sdk installer.

I know this is a beta but can anyone help me get passed this message and get the angular spa to come up?

[image][image]

Comment: You must post your stacktrace or error instead of linking to it.

Comment: The error is right there on the image. It's not a link to a website. And it's a compilation/dependency error so no stack to show.

Comment: @myfunnyfella Check the answer posted here https://forums.asp.net/t/2146663.aspx?Unable+to+build+same+project+on+new+machine+rzc+generate+exited+with+code+2147450750

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't apply to me @MohsinMehmood. It looks similar but the error code is different, I'm using Visual Studio Code and the issue happens on the command line so updating visual studio or adding OS patches as the solution suggest is irrelevant.

Comment: There should be a problem in global nuget packages. Something like mishmash in versions. Can you try to load the packages in the app folder or to reinstall them. I have tried the same like you (.NET Core SDK (3.0.100-alpha1-009456)) and it is working without a problem.